# Hue api id identification

Tags: javascript, json, api

I'm in the process of making my own philips hue controller via javascript. and I am trying to identify groups and light id's. But i can't figure out how I get the JSON id of a group or light.

I get an http answer in JSON format what looks like this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "name": "Woonkamer",
        "lights": [
            "2",
            "1",
            "4"
        ],
        "sensors": [],
        "type": "Room",
        "state": {
            "all_on": true,
            "any_on": true
        },
        "recycle": false,
        "class": "Living room",
        "action": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 144,
            "hue": 12057,
            "sat": 143,
            "effect": "none",
            "xy": [
                0.502,
                0.4204
            ],
            "ct": 447,
            "alert": "select",
            "colormode": "xy"
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "name": "keuken",
        "lights": [
            "3"
        ],
        "sensors": [],
        "type": "Room",
        "state": {
            "all_on": true,
            "any_on": true
        },
        "recycle": false,
        "class": "Kitchen",
        "action": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 254,
            "ct": 366,
            "alert": "select",
            "colormode": "ct"
        }
    },
```

I have no problem with accessing for example the type and name, but I have no idea how to access the id's that are written at the start of each section. I cant just get the first index because then I just get the other objects like name etc.

My current function looks like this where I access the room name, but I also need the room id. Keep in mind this code looks awful because I'm quite new to JS

```
function getGroups()
    {
        var url = "https://"+ipadress+"/api/"+username+"/groups";
        request.open("GET", url);
        request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        request.send();

        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                const res = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
                for(var i = 1; i < Object.keys(res).length; i++)
               {
                    if(res[i] != null)
                    {
                        if(res[i].type == "Room")
                        {
                            var name = res[i].name;
                            document.getElementById("light_container").style.display = "block";
                            var onoff = document.createElement('input');
                            onoff.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                            onoff.setAttribute('id', name);
                            onoff.setAttribute('value', name); //need to change this to dynamic function that reads the hue
                            onoff.setAttribute('onclick', 'changeState("/groups/'+name+'/action")') //need to make change state function
                            document.body.appendChild(onoff);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there in the API response is an object. Right now you are only accessing its values, not yet its keys. You can change the way your for loop works to use the object keys as index instead. Then `i` will be the room id you are looking for.

```
for (var i in res) {
 ....  // everything inside the for loop can stay the same
       // but now "i" is the room id you are looking for.
}
```